# Remapping 0x32 (Non-US # and ~) to 0x35 (Grave Accent and Tilde) has no effect

Tags: keyboard

I have a Italian Macbook Pro. It has a pretty useless <kbd>ù§</kbd> key that I want to remap to <kbd>`~</kbd>.

It appears that the hex usage ID for that <kbd>ù§</kbd> key is `0x32` i.e. the Non-US # and ~ key, according to Footnote 2 (inserted at pg 56 of the [USB spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) and found at pg 59..You can find it easily by finding the `§` symbol in the document). I also consulted the often linked [Apple Technical Note page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017618-CH1-KEY_TABLE_USAGES), and couldn't find another possible key.

So with that information, I've been trying to use `hidutil` to set the  0x32 (Keyboard Non-US # and ~) to 0x35 (Grave Accent and Tilde). It seems it has no effect. Other key changes work, just not that one. Here's my code:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": 
    [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000032,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035}]
}'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The characters actually produced by hardware keys are determined by the system layout mapping software (on MacOS by the active Input Source).  On the Italian layout, there is no key which is mapped to backtik/tilde, so I don't think there is any way to change some other key to produce that via a keyswapping system like hidutil. You have to use key remapping software like Ukelele or Karabiner.

Answer (score -1):

#### Incorrect keycode

Firstly, the "`ù§`" (it's actually only `ù` since `§` can only be obtained through a combination of keys) key's hexadecimal keycode (or usage ID) is not 0x32, it's 0x31.

Don't forget that you are using an Italian keyboard. The location of keys and therefore their keycodes are different from other keyboards. The `ù and §` key on the [Italian keyboard](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/italian_keyboard.png) is located at the same place as the `\ and |` key on the [International English keyboard](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/en_international_keyboard.png). According to the [Technical Note TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017618-CH1-KEY_TABLE_USAGES), the hex. usage ID for `\ and |` is 0x31. So the keycode for the `ù and §` key on the Italian keyboard is 0x31.

#### Corrected code

Your command is also incorrect in another way.

I understood you want the command to *replace* the function of the `ù and §` key by the one of the  `[backtick] and ~` key. But what it does is that it tries to *add* the function of the `ù and §` to the `[grave accent] and ~` key (with no success of course).

Still according to the Technical Note TN2450, your command actually contains about half of the needed parameters in it. Once you have added the function of the `[grave accent] and ~` to the `ù and §` key, you have to set the function of the `[grave accent] and ~` *key* (not character) to something else (generally `ù and §` but can be none).

So the command should be :

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000031,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000035,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000031}]}'
```

Keep in mind that :

- **Src** is the key function you will change
- **Dst** is the key function that it will be changed to

The above command should "swap" the function of the two keys, setting the function of 0x31 to 0x35 and 0x35 to 0x31. Meaning that when you press the `ù and §` , you will get the expected result for the `[grave accent] and ~` and same the other way. To set 0x31 to 0x35 and 0x35 to none :

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000031,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000035,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":[]}]}'
```

This means that when you press the `ù and §` , you will get the expected result for the `[grave accent] and ~` but when you press `[grave accent] and ~`, you will get nothing.

Note 1: AFAIK, `hidutil` won't work for characters obtained through a key combination.

Note 2: The parameters will reset to default each time you reboot, meaning that you will have to run the command at each bootup.

Comment: Same comment as before.  What do you *think* this “script” is doing here?  It’s clear you copied this from somewhere else without understanding what is happening or why they function the way they do.

Comment: @Allan This script replaces the key with the keycode `0x32` (which is the key for ù and §) or `0x700000032` with the key with the keycode `0x35` (which is the key for [backtick] and ~) or `0x700000035`. And the other way round.

Comment: First, why are you *swapping* keys?  Is that required by `hidutil` or what was asked?  Second, why do you assume the keys on a keyboard is inextricably linked to the character it generates and third, how do you know that the original character doesn’t require a modifier to be generated?

Comment: @Allan What was asked was to fix the script, what I think I did. Also, according to various `hidutil` keycode lists, the keycodes are correct and work with those keys.

Comment: You didn’t answer *any* of my questions which, had you done so, would probably give you insight as to why someone down voted this.

Comment: @Allan Alright. 1. I do not know this parameter really well but I did some research to learn about it before posting and I concluded that the OP's script wasn't working because he only transferred a key to another without transferring the other key somewhere else. 2. I think it is required because else it won't work; and the OP asked how to fix his script, so I think so. 3. Because that's how a keyboard works, isn't it? 4. You may have a point on that, I'll check and update the answer tomorrow after some deeper research about that. Got more questions? ;)

Comment: You seem to be missing the overall point here which is “you don’t know the answer.”  That’s ok because none of us are born knowing these things and had to learn, just like you will. To understand what’s going on here, research “Dunning Kruger”.  Take time to understand **before** posting.

Comment: @Allan I have edited the answer after some research. I think it is good now. Can I have some feedback? :)

Comment: No.  On the technical side you are still confusing remapping keys with characters. There’s a reason why we recommend things like Karabiner instead of doing this with `hdiutil`

Comment: Have you actually tested your solution with the Italian input source active?

Comment: @TomGewecke No, I wasn't able to.